# my sqlyog and powershell are connecting to different mysql in my local

Tags: mysql, bash, powershell, shell, sqlyog

my sqlyog and powershell are connecting to different mysql in my local. There is no trouble connecting, both connections are successful but the I cant see the tables which I created in sqlyog when I connect using powershell.

I am expecting my powershell to show same dbs which I created using sqlyog